In CE, CB, and CC configurations, what determines the polarities of the voltages applied to the C, B, and E terminals of the transistors?
In the transistor configurations below, in some cases a positive DC voltage is applied to the base and collector, while in other cases a positive DC voltage is applied to the emitter and a negative voltage to the collector.
My question, which is the same as the title, is: what determines the polarity of these DC voltages?



Link

These circuit diagrams are difficult to grasp as they are counterintuitive and do not align well with real-world applications.

The type transistor determines the biasing polarity.
In general, an NPN is biased with the base slightly more positive than the emitter, and the collector more positive than the base. For a PNP the base is slightly more negative than the emitter and the collector is more negative than the base.
There are some exceptions such as Class C where the base is biased at the same potential as the emitter or even slightly negative compared to the emitter in NPN and slightly positive from the emitter in PNP.
You also have to take into account what reference point is being used, for example for a PNP CE circuit you will sometimes see the collector voltage shown as negative with the emitter towards ground, sometimes it will be shown as the collector towards ground and the emitter positive. It works the same, it's just a matter of calling either the positive of the supply or the negative of the supply ground.
In your first diagram with a PNP CB the base is at ground potential but if you look at it the base is slightly more negative than the emitter and the collector is more negative than the base, so the convention holds regardless of what point you call ground.

Understanding by experimenting
An (NPN) transistor is characterized by positive base-emitter and collector-emitter voltages. Let's investigate through a series of "virtuoso" CircuitLab experiments how this is achieved. Here are some explanations regarding their implementation.
Voltage source polarity: Since the symbol used to denote a voltage source has a constant polarity regardless of the voltage sign, I preferred to change the polarity of the sources by flipping them and adding a minus sign in the label.
Voltage visualization: Voltage sources are ideal sources that maintain a constant voltage regardless of the load. Therefore, voltmeters are not necessary to measure their output. I  have only indicated the voltage drop across the collector resistor by replacing it with a voltmeter with a 1 kΩ internal resistance. The collector-emitter voltage is not indicated but can be visually determined by the equation: Vce = Vcc - VRc - Ve.
Beating Early effect: To make this conceptual circuit "ideal", we will use a clever trick to overcome the Early effect. To this end, we will adjust the supply voltage so that there is a constant 2 V across the collector-emitter part of the transistor (cascode circuits do it).
Floating input voltage source
The simplest way to control a BJT is to apply the input voltage Vbe directly to the base-emitter junction of the transistor. Let's set it (Vbe = 711 mV) so that we get a 7 mA current flowing through the collector. This current will cause a 7 V drop across Rc, leaving us with a 2 V drop across the transistor.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
However, in many cases, the input source will be floating (as in the schematic above), which is usually unacceptable.
Grounded input voltage sources
That is why, we typically establish the input voltage by using two grounded voltage sources; one source (Vb) is connected to the base, and the other (Ve) to the emitter. The input voltage is then the difference between these two voltages - Vbe = Vb - Ve.
Common mode
Positive Vb=1.711V, positive Ve=1V, positive Vcc=10V: Let's first set all voltages positive keeping the same difference Vbe = 711 mV.

simulate this circuit
Positive Vb=711mV, zero Ve, positive Vcc=9V: Now, let's lower all voltages by 1 V. As a result, Ve will become 0 V.

simulate this circuit
This simply means that the emitter is grounded and there is only one input voltage Vb applied to the base (that is why this circuit is called "grounded-emitter stage"). Since Vbe is the same, Ic and VRc do not change.

simulate this circuit
Zero Vb, negative Ve=-711 mV, positive Vcc=8.289V: Then continue lowering the voltages by 711 mV. As a result, Vb will become 0 V.

simulate this circuit
This actually means that the base is grounded and there is only one (negative) input voltage Ve applied to the emitter (that is why this circuit can be called "grounded-base stage"). Vbe is the same, so Ic and VRc do not change.

simulate this circuit
Negative Vb=-5V, negative Ve=-5.711V, positive Vcc=3.289V: It is starting to get interesting (not like in a textbook:-) Now we decide to make both input voltages strongly negative and significantly reduce the supply voltage.

simulate this circuit
Surprisingly, the circuit still works really well.
Negative Vb=-8.289V, negative Ve=-9V, zero Vcc: Let's push it even further - we make the input voltages even more negative and set the supply voltage to zero.

simulate this circuit
That means no power supply, it is shorted. How can the transistor still work?

simulate this circuit
Oh, I see... Ve is doing its job.
Negative Vb=-10V, negative Ve=-10.711V, negative Vcc=-1.711V: Well, this is already impossible - an NPN transistor with a negative supply voltage?!?!

simulate this circuit
But it still works! The reason is that the effective voltage Ve - Vcc > 0.
Common emitter
Finally, let's explore the classic common-emitter configuration by "lifting" the emitter with a constant positive voltage Ve and varying the base voltage Vb as the input.

simulate this circuit

Common base
Then, let's swap the positions of the sources to examine the classic common-base circuit.

simulate this circuit


In all cases, emitter current flows in the direction of its arrow, with the emitter terminal being the most positive or most negative, depending on the transistor polarity.
It's unfortunate that in the example you were given, the polarity of the transistor was switched from PNP for the common base amplifier to NPN for the common collector and emitter amplifiers.

The application for which the transistors are used in CE, CB or CC would determine the polarity of voltages at collector, emitter and base of a BJT. Depending on the voltages,the BJT can be made to switch on or off. The voltages across and collector and emitter are used to set the bias conditions and to indicate the flow of currents. The arrow in a BJT indicates the flow of DC current.
After the BJT is biased which means its initial conditions such as DC voltages and DC currents are setup , the ac small signal to be amplified is connected to it an appropriate terminal for amplification.
In the circuits shown above, \$V_{in} \$ is the signal to be amplified. The voltages \$V_{BC}\$ in first,\$V_{CE}\$ in second circuit,\$V_{CE}\$ in the third circuit are used to bias the BJT. Note that the BJT in the first circuit is PNP where as BJTs in the second and third are NPN. These would require different biasing condtions. The PNP transistor as a general rule would have a higher voltage at the emitter than at the base and voltage at the emitter would be higher than voltage at the collector whatever those polarities may be. The NPN as a general rule would have higher voltage at the collector than the emittter and the emitter would have lower voltage than at the base, whatever those polarities may be. These are the two things to note. Polarities of those voltages are irrelevant and have to be determined as per the application such as how much voltage or current is needed at a terminal or across a resistor.
In summary, polarities of voltages across the terminals of a BJT are unimportant. The important thing is that difference in voltages between certain two terminals of the BJT in each configuration as in previous para should be positive for the BJT to be in active region of operation which means the BJT is on.

In order for current and voltage amplification to occur, the operating point of a BJT must be in the active or linear region of the collector characteristic curves of the transistor. This means that the base-collector junction must be reverse biased, while the base-emitter junction must be forward biased. Therefore, in an NPN BJT, the collector will have a higher potential than the base, while the base will have a higher potential than the emitter. The opposite is true for a PNP BJT. The fact that the base-collector junction must be reverse biased causes the depletion region of this junction to widen and it is home to a strong electric field that captures minority carriers from the base region and launches them, accelerating them into the collector region. This is independent of the type of configuration, i.e. CB, CC, CE.
